# Editing a logo in A1 format and EPS format

Tags: image-editing

Somebody designed a logo for me and gave it to me in PNG and Jpg format.  I upgraded to get the logo design in "editable" formats.  He sent me it in A1 and EPS formats.  How do I edit a logo in A1 Format, or EPS format without having to subscribe to adobe illustrator?

Comment: I assume you mean AI not A1. Do you ahve **any** vector editing tools? CorelDraw, Inkscape, Sketch, Xara??

Comment: [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/download/) is totally free, [Sketch](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/) and [XARA](http://www.xara.com/us/designer-pro/download/) provide free trial.

Comment: If you use Inkscape, ask if you can get an SVG or PDF version which may be easier to open than the EPS.

Comment: Oh, but that said: Why do you want to edit the logo? Ideally, you hire a designer to give you the best option. A that point, you hopefully never have to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Illustrator (.ai) files and Encapsulated Postscript (.eps) files can be edited in just about any modern drawing program, such as CorelDraw, (possibly) Inkscape. While these files were likely created in Adobe Illustrator you may be able to extract/import the file for editing purposes. You can also use Adobe Photoshop (type programs) by "rasterizing" (setting a pixel size) the file.
I would start by downloading an open source editor and see if you can do what you need with that.

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape is supposed to let you open and edit ai files. According to it's docs, it converts files to SVG format and data is lost if you try to return to ai format.

While Inkscape is free and runs on the major desktop platforms, I could not get to run on my mac.

If you want to simply view the file but not edit it, there is a popular vector app called Sketch that imports ai as static images but retains their vector resolution.

http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/

Inkscape is Professional level (free) open-sourced graphic editor that is supported on Linux, Windows and Mac 10.5-10.10

Mac Users must also install the XQuartz (free) open-sourced library

Here is a link to known apps that can open ai files:
http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/

Comment: I finally got Inkscape to run on Mac OS Yosemite. It takes a while to load the first time. I could NOT get it to open an AI file correctly.

Comment: Since this post, I discovered Affinity Designer. It seems to do a good job of opening AI files. https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/ <- it is often available  for $49.95 - This is a Mac only app. - it may also be found in the Apple App store.